# org-mode change diary timestamp from agenda list

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have configured org-agenda to use an org-mode diary file. Sometimes I would like to adjust the timestamp for a diary entry from the agenda.

<kbd>i</kbd> (`org-agenda-diary-entry`) inserts diary entries with a bare timestamp rather than a `SCHEDULED` property. This means using <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> in the agenda will add an additional timestamp rather than adjust the existing one.

- Is there a correct way to adjust diary timestamps from the agenda?
- Failing that, what's the best way to hook into `org-agenda-diary-entry` so I can turn that bare timestamp into a `SCHEDULED` property?

Answer (score 1):

Just found it. <kbd>></kbd> (`org-agenda-date-prompt`)